# How to rotate a group of figures (subfigure)

Tags: subfloats, rotating

3 figures side by side...

I want to put them horizontally, so that you need to rotate the book by 90° to read the figures and captions.

Now, I want to rotate this:

```
   \begin{figure}[]
\subfigure{
        \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{figures/a.png}
    }
    \label{sub:graph}
\subfigure{
        \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{figures/b.png}
    }
    \label{sub:mobile}
\subfigure{
        \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{figures/c.png}
    }
    \label{sub:dsk}

\caption{Main cap. \ref{sub:graph} sub cap1 \ref{sub:mobile} sub cap2 and \ref{sub:desktop} sub cap3.}
\label{fig:myFig}
   \end{figure}
```

Comment: Do you mean "vertically"? Do you want the `subfigure` *and* `figure` caption to be rotated? Should the images then be stretched to `0.28\textheight`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another way is to use the `sidewaysfigure` environment from the `rotating` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.28\textheight]{figures/a.png}\quad
  \includegraphics[width=0.28\textheight]{figures/b.png}\quad
  \includegraphics[width=0.28\textheight]{figures/c.png}
  \caption{Caption for the three rotated figures\label{fig:test}}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

This could be combined with `subfig` to have captions for each figure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[First figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textheight]{figures/a.png}\label{fig:a}} \quad
  \subfloat[Second figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textheight]{figures/b.png}\label{fig:b}}\quad
  \subfloat[Third figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textheight]{figures/c.png}\label{fig:c}}
  \caption{Caption for the three rotated figures\label{fig:test}}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: simplest solution I found so far.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an option using the [hvfloat](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hvfloat) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hvfloat}

\begin{document}

\hvFloat[%
nonFloat=true,%
capWidth=h,%
capPos=r,%
objectAngle=90,%
capAngle=90,%
objectPos=l%
]{figure}{%
\includegraphics[width=0.28\textheight]{figures/a.png}\quad
\includegraphics[width=0.28\textheight]{figures/b.png}\quad
\includegraphics[width=0.28\textheight]{figures/c.png}
}%
[Rotated Caption]{%
Caption for the three rotated figures}{fig:test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option would be to use `\rotatebox` from the graphicx package and some `minipage`s; the captions can be obtained with `\captionof` from the caption package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens,subrefformat=parens,labelsep=space}

\begin{document}

\rotatebox{90}{%
  \stepcounter{figure}%
  \begin{minipage}{\textheight}
  \begin{minipage}{.33\textheight}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{figures/a.png}
    \captionof{subfigure}[]{First subfigure}%
    \label{sub:graph}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.33\textheight}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{figures/b.png}
    \captionof{subfigure}[]{Second subfigure}%
    \label{sub:mobile}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.33\textheight}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{figures/c.png}
    \captionof{subfigure}[]{Third subfigure}%
    \label{sub:desktop}
  \end{minipage}%
  \addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
  \captionof{figure}{Main cap. \ref{sub:graph} sub cap1 \ref{sub:mobile} sub cap2 and \ref{sub:desktop} sub cap3.}
  \end{minipage}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]