# Sideways subfigure over several pages

Tags: packages, subfloats, rotating

I am trying to include "sideways" subfigures according to this question [How to rotate a group of figures (subfigure)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37600/how-to-rotate-a-group-of-figures-subfigure)
from Torbjørn T.

I would like to put three graphics next to each other (for comparison reason) and continue this "threerow". And in case I need more than one page it should just continue for the next page.
Something like that (in case 9 picture do not fit, then just 6 or even 3).

```
= = =
= = = 
= = =
```

I guess it might be a problem with the package subfig because including it causes an error. Is there any problem due to other packages I use?

Here are my packages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=4cm]{geometry}
%Font encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%Font
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%Language
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%Mathematics
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textgreek}
%Graphs and Diagrams
%\usepackage{subgraphic}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%Tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[labelsep=newline,% line break after label
   justification=raggedright,
   singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\bfseries 
\sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%Writing
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
%Misc
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
%References
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\begin{document}
\end{sidewaysfigure} 
\centering
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
  \caption[]{Caption for the three rotated figures. \label{fig:test}}
    \begin{minipage}{\textheight}
    \footnotesize test test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test test 
    \bigskip
    \end{minipage}
  \subfloat[First figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue1.eps}\label{fig:a}} \quad 
  \subfloat[Second figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue2.eps}\label{fig:b}}\quad 
  \subfloat[Third figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue3.eps}\label{fig:c}} \quad 
    \subfloat[First figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue1.eps}\label{fig:d}} \quad 
  \subfloat[Second figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue3.eps}\label{fig:e}}\quad 
  \subfloat[Third figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue3.eps}\label{fig:f}} 

\end{sidewaysfigure}
\clearpage
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
  \ContinuedFloat             %%<-- put this in subsequest figures.
  \centering
  \subfloat[First figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue1.eps}\label{fig:d}} \quad
  \subfloat[Second figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue3.eps}\label{fig:e}}\quad
  \subfloat[Third figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue3.eps}\label{fig:f}}
  \caption[]{Caption for the three rotated figures\label{fig:test}}
  %%% Use empty optional argument in \caption[] for subsequest figures.
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0.1pt}  % default value: 6.0pt

\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Summary Statistics}
\label{tab:SummaryStatistics}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}%
  { @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l d{5.0} *{7}{d{2.3}} }
\toprule
Variables\tnote{a} 
& \mc{\hphantom{$-$}N$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}Mean$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}St.\,Dev.$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}Min.$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}Q1$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}Median$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}Q3$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}Max.} \\ [0.5ex]
\midrule
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\itshape Earnings Surprise} \\ [0.5ex]
SUE1
 & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}14070$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$0.001$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.182$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$7.450$\hphantom{^{**}}$} &\mc{$-$0.003$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.001$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.005$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}6.240} \\
SUE2
 & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}14081$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.000$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.154$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$7.440$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$0.002$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.001$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.005$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}6.250} \\
SUE3
 & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}12604$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$0.001$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.134$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$8.180$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.000$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.001$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.002$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}7.090} \\  [0.5ex]
\midrule
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\itshape Firm Characteristics} \\ [0.5ex]
CASC (in \%)
 & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}12309$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.016$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.370$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$0.803$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$0.098$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.000$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.098$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.992} \\
BHAR (in \%)
 & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}13885$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.325$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}10.315$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$19.233$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$6.571$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.168$\hphantom{^{***}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}6.984$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}21.034} \\
DVOLA
 & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}13866$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.000$\hphantom{^{**}}$}  & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.004$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$0.043$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$0.001$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.000$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.001$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.104} \\
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
Market Value of\\ \noindent\hspace*{3mm}Equity (in mio)
\end{tabular} 
& \mc{\hphantom{$-$}14012$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}21467$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}40919$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}52$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}3329$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}8082$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}20408$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}510201} \\
LEVERAGE
 & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}12756$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.299$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.203$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.000$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.144$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.252$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.420$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}1.000} \\
DLEVERAGE
 & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}12107$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.001$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.042$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$0.274$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$0.017$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$0.002$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.015$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.461} \\
UPGRADE
 & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}14094$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.022$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.148$\hphantom{^{**}}$} &  \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.000$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.000$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.000$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.000$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}1.000} \\
DOWNGRADE
 & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}14094$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.036$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.186$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.000$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.000$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.000$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.000$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}1.000} \\ [0.5ex]
\midrule
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\itshape Macroeconomic Variables} \\ [0.5ex]
SPOT
 & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}14058$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.029$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.014$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.006$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.019$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.030$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.041$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.052} \\
DSPOT
 & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}13489$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$0.001$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.004$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$0.016$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$0.003$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.000$\hphantom{^{***}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.002$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.013} \\
SLOPE
 & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}14058$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.014$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.010$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$0.002$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.003$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.016$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.023$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.029} \\
DSLOPE
 & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}13489$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.000$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.003$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$0.011$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$0.003$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{$-$0.001$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.002$\hphantom{^{**}}$} & \mc{\hphantom{$-$}0.012} \\ [1ex]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item[a] A table-specific footnote
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

It appears first the six subfigures, then the table and the remaining subfigures. How can I avoid the table to "sneak" into my figures?

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0.1pt}  % default value: 6.0pt
\caption{Earnings Surprises and Cumulative Returns}
\label{tab:surprises}
```

In case there are mutually exclusiv packages, what can I do (other than to use a different way of putting my graphics)?

Thank you very much.

**EDIT:** With the help of Harish Kumar I could make it almost work, still I am confronted with some issues.

Additionally (maybe not appropriate for this answer), is it possible to avoid the linebreak after the caption just(!) for figures (I am required to do that for tables).

Comment: Please read this post: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) regarding MWE. Your code does not qualify to be called a MWE.

Comment: Dear Harish, as my code does not even work, so I did not post an MWE. But the example is exactly the one like in the question posted (from Torbjørn T.).

Answer (score 1):

`subfig` provides `\ContinuedFloat` command to be used like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[First figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textheight]{figures/a.png}\label{fig:a}} \quad
  \subfloat[Second figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textheight]{figures/b.png}\label{fig:b}}\quad
  \subfloat[Third figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textheight]{figures/c.png}\label{fig:c}}
  \caption{Caption for the three rotated figures\label{fig:test}}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\clearpage
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
  \ContinuedFloat             %%<-- put this in subsequest figures.
  \centering
  \subfloat[First figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textheight]{figures/a.png}\label{fig:d}} \quad
  \subfloat[Second figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textheight]{figures/b.png}\label{fig:e}}\quad
  \subfloat[Third figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textheight]{figures/c.png}\label{fig:f}}
  \caption[]{Caption for the three rotated figures\label{fig:test}}
  %%% Use empty optional argument in \caption[] for subsequest figures.
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Harish, thank you for your answer. Would it be possible to place the three RHS subfigures to the "top" of the page (like the subfigures on the LHS)? or is like a book style (both-side printing)? moreover, I have a problem using \subfig do you see any problems in the package I am using?

Comment: EDIT: it works! I do not even need to load the \subfig package, but I do not know why, there is a "gap page" between the two pages, like figures- table? - figures (I have created a table after your code).